# RASA NLU Trainer fails when Unicode characters are used

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

When I added unicode characters to my RASA NLU response templates, which is domain.yml file, while training the model the following error occurs.

```
templates:
  utter_greet:
  - text: " ආයුබෝවන් "

  utter_cheer_up:
  - text: "Well, Life always brings you something!"

  utter_did_that_help:
  - text: "Are you ok now ?"

  utter_happy:
  - text: "OK, nice!"
```

And the error was:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 195: character maps to <undefined>


<CoreError: error code 3: Unable to load any data from source yaml file: Path: '/'>
```

This is the full error in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pykwalify\core.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.source = yaml.load(stream)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 195: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 450, in validate_domain_yaml
    schema_files=[schema_file])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pykwalify\core.py", line 78, in __init__
    raise CoreError(u"Unable to load any data from source yaml file")
pykwalify.errors.CoreError: <CoreError: error code 3: Unable to load any data from source yaml file: Path: '/'>
```

I added some Sinhala unicode characters (ආයුබෝවන්) to get the response in my native language. That's when the error occured. Is there any solution this can fix with ?

Comment: could you find the solution for this. i am also getting an error when unicode characters included in the domain file.

Comment: No, I was unable to find a solution.